# How to retreive an email template stored in Public Email Templates using metadata?

Tags: email-template, metadata-api

I created a email template directly in the email tab of contact and saved it as a template in `Public Email Templates folder`. How can I retreive this email template stored in My templates -> Public Email Templates using metadata? I have tried using `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:Public\Email\Templates\/My_Email_Template`. Also tried from package.xml. I get `No results found`.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same issue, this worked for me:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m EmailTemplate:unfiled\$public\/My_template_API_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below syntax in your package.xml:

```
<types>
<members>unfiled$public</members>
<members>unfiled$public/Your_Template_Unique_Name</members>
<name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
```

The Unfiled Public Email Templates folder name in Salesforce is unfiled$public.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: tried it. says no results found.

Comment: @nSv23 What is the template type? please confirm if  "Available For Use" is checked or not. Manage Public Classic Email Templates/Manage Public LightningEmail Templates permission is checked at profile level.

Comment: I didnt create it from setup. I created from contacts page. You have a tab for email in contacts page. You click it, and you have save as template option. I was only able to save it Public Email Templates folder (a default saleforce folder)

Comment: If understand correctly you created lightning template. Seems that currently you cannot import and deploy it as other metadata. You can however, import and export it with data loader as data  -https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EDG9QAO

Comment: @LironC what i did was I created a scratch org and replicated the template and in VS code when I did pull changes from scratch org., I was able to download it, but its downloaded into the folder: email/unified$public with name of my template with underscores for spaces followed by some numbers like this my_template_148587510.